# How can I limit a rewarded video ad length (admob)?

Tags: admob

My app uses a rewarded video ad but in my opinion, sometimes the ads are too long.
how can I set a limit for how long an ad can be?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long is too long ? Couple of minutes, or ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a feature offered by AdMob. Ads that feel too long will generally receive fewer clicks, though, and therefore be shown less and less often as the system adjusts.