# change 25 sec admob video into 10 sec

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob

following code uses crossMTAdmob publig in xamarin and it loads a 25 seconds admob video

25 sec is too long, is there way to change it to 10 sec video?

```
 string addID = "ca-app-pub-55555555/1234";

 CrossMTAdmob.Current.OnRewardedVideoAdLoaded += (s, args) =>
            {
                CrossMTAdmob.Current.ShowRewardedVideo();
            };

CrossMTAdmob.Current.LoadRewardedVideo(addID);
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that their TOS don't allow you to do this.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052452/how-can-i-limit-a-rewarded-video-ad-length-admob

Comment: I am new to xamarin, and working on launch my first small app. I can really use your debuging help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239018/xamarin-image-is-not-displaying-in-release

Comment: If you want to use a 10 sec admon video, you could try to use a 10 sec rewarded video ad unit from a different ad provider.